# How can I animate a matrix of squares so they "grow" from one corner to the other

Tags: animation, mesh

I want go be able to have a group of objects such as planes grow out of thin air to their full shape but rather than all of them at the same time that they do so from one corner to another, sort of like when you taper a curve with another (and I tried turning my objects into a curve and doing that but it did not work, I know I could key every single one but is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Is it to be static or dynamic (animation)?

Comment: A static animation, dynamic would be nice! but static would do the job.

Comment: I think Animation Nodes is a flexible way to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfXUGdyICHg. You can also ray cast to a surface if needed. But could you describe the curve you are talking about?

Comment: If you have a curve either path or circle, and you bevel it with a second curve, then if you taper it with a third circle you can control the thickness of that extruded shape with the path just as if you were playing with curves for an animation.

Comment: as far as the animation, I already know how to do that video, but if you look at for example the trailer for the gtx 1080ti, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=26lSLWNiUZY You will notice at the beginning how the crystal formations grow and more akin to what I am asking at around 0:25 you can see the micro ships "generating" out of thin air.